# Which scriptures mention Siva beheading Brahma?

Tags: shiva, brahma, punishment

This is not the same as Rudra stabbing Prajapati at the request of the other Gods for his incest with his daughter.

Comment: Some of the tags you create are just mind blowing.. like "beheading" in this case.. :D

Comment: watered it down @rickross :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Chapter 8, Vidyeswara Samhita of Shiva Mahapurana** says Shiva created "Kala Bhairava" from his eyebrows to behead Brahma when Brahma lied about top of infinite Linga.  Bhairava is nothing but Lord Shiva as described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18154/3500) (translated by Shantilal Nagar)

> नन्दिकेश्वर उवाच 
>   ससर्जाथ महादेवः पुरुषं कञ्चिदद्भुतम्। 
>  भैरवाख्यं
>   ध्रुवोर्मध्याद्ब्रह्मदर्पजिघांसया। १॥
>
> Nandi said:
>   Thereafter, Šiva, in order to shatter the pride of Brahma, produced an
>   astonishing type of a person from out of his eyebrows.
>
> स वै तदा तत्र पतिं प्रणम्य शिवमङ्गणे। 
>  किं कार्यं करवाण्यत्र
>   शीघ्रमाज्ञापय प्रभो!।। २॥
>
> Soon after his emerging, he offered his salutation to lord Siva in the
>   battle ground itself and asked him, “O Lord, what have I to do? You
>   kindly get me the command at once.”
>
> शिव उवाच 
>  वत्स योऽयं विधिः साक्षाञ्जगतामाद्यदैवतम्। 
>  नूनमर्चय
>   खड्गं स्वं तिग्मेन जवसा परम्।। ३।।
>
> Siva said, “O Bhairava, you better, adore Brahma, the primeval lord of
>   the earth, with a sharp edged Sword (or kill him)'.
>
> स वै गृहीत्वैककरेण केशंतत्पञ्चमं दृप्तमसत्यभाषिणम्। 
>  छित्वा शिरो
>   हास्य निहन्तुमुद्यतः प्रकम्पयन्खड्गमतिस्फुटं करैः।। ४।
>
> On hearing this Rudra caught hold of the hair of Brahma's head in his
>   hand, and severed his fifth head which told the untruth and got ready
>   to kill him.

Also, **Chapter 35, Rudra Samhita (Sati Khanda) of Shiva Mahapurana** says Kalabhairava of Kashi cut the head of Brahma.

> श्रीकालभैरव: काश्यां नखाग्रेणौव लीलया। 
>  पुरा शिरश्च चिच्छेद पञ्चमं
>   ब्रह्मणो ध्रुवम्॥५२।।
>
> Kalabhairava at Kasi had cut off Brahma's head even by Scratching with
>   the nails.

**Chapter 14, Uttaraardha Arunachala Mahatmya of Skanda Purana** gives different narrative here which could be due to Kalpa Bheda and it says  Shiva banished Brahma's worship when he lied he saw top of Linga.

Comment: Didn't Vishnu try to intercede on Brahma's behalf? @the destroyer

Comment: @SK Not here. He was silent but He saved Brahma when Shiva was about to attack Brahma during Shiva's marriage.

Comment: Is it eyebrow or nail  from where KalaBhaira came ? Also there are 2 corrections you have to make ... The reason for "beheading" on of the Bhrama's head was the ego he had since he was the "creator". " Brahma lied about top of infinite Linga" is the reason Bhrama was cursed to be not worshipped

Answer (score 2):

I have heard from learned persons, the answer as follows:
Lord Shiva marries Maa. Parvathi. Lord Brahma conducts the marriage as the main priest. After the marriage, Shiva was very happy and wanted to give a gift to Brahma. Shiva asks Brahma to make his wish. Brahma with 5 heads at that time was very high headed and wanted to insult Shiva. He tells Shiva that whatever Shiva wants to give him, he shall have to give him in a direction which is not seen by
by him. Brahma having 5 heads, is looking in every direction! Shiva gets angry on Brahma for insulting him. Shiva snaps one head of Brahma from his finger nails.As Brahma is a Brahman, Shiva gets Brahma-hatya-dosha and the Brahma-kapala(Brahma's head) gets stuck in his hand. Any effort from Shiva to get rid of Brahma-kapala was in vain. 
then Lord Vishnu suggests that he shall go begging from person to person. Whose so ever Bhiksha(alm) fills the Brahma-kapala, it will fall off from Shiva's hand. 
Shiva goes on begging from person to person in all 3 Lokas. Nobody was able to fill the Brahma-kapala. Frustrated, Shiva begs his consort Parvathi for Bhiksha.
She fills it with food. Immediately, the Brahma-kapala snaps from Shivas hand and falls down. Parvathi becomes Annapoorneshwari, providing food for the universe.
This is how the story goes.