# Should one always abide by his parents' will or can he go against it only if he is right?

Tags: karma, dharma, moksha, guru, spirituality

I want to ask this question with the help of a real life scenario. Basically, what if one wants to pursue an educational field associating with this world just for a living so that he can progress in the spiritual path to attain union with the help of a Satguru, but his father doesn't merely want him to stay in the same country and do nothing special materialistically. Instead, he wants him to live abroad and progress immensely in this world and make a name for himself. The father might allow it but will be disappointed and unhappy with him along with some other people. Lets suppose the son listens to himself and disappoints his father, will this be violating Dharma? Because it is our respective duty to keep our parents' will in consideration. Plus, it may also be bad Karma making his parents unhappy. And it is also said by many saints and rishis that if we do anything even good against our parents' will, it will be of no benefit to us. But that may not be the case when one's parents are completely wrong and there is no good in what they are thinking. But regardless of that, my consciousness tells me that fulfilling your parents' desires is the better path to choose. But I would like to hear what the scriptures have to say about this.

Comment: Currently this question look like personal advice. I think your question is good and related to Hinduism. You should edit your question to make it generalize.

Comment: Hinduism gives you full right to choose your own path in life. Let me show you an example... In begening of mankind Daksha(Son of lord Brahma) was selected as [Prajapati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prajapati). He had 3 or 4 (not sure how many) sons and Daksha's full faith was on his son that one day, one of his some will take resposibilites of Prajapati and other sons will help him in his duties towards Prajapati. But his all sons got inspired by Dev Rishi Narad's (Brother of Daksha and some of Brahma) teaching and decided to take sanyas to get moksha [continue...]

Comment: . In sanyas, we have to leave our house and start living as Sanyasi in jungle (means away from crowd so our tapasya won't get disturbed). When Daksha come to know about their son'e this decision than he try to convince him to not go for sanyas but thier son didn't listen to him and decided to spend all their life in lotus feet of Narayan. Daksha got angry on it, he came to know that it was Narad who taught his son this path and in ager he put curse on Narad... "My son is leaving my house, they are now homeless. [contunue...]

Comment: They have to travel world without having a home. And same will happen to you... You will also never have any home, you have to routing all loks by chanting name of Narayan. Narad got very happy with this curse of his brother and reply to him that Thank you my brother, you give me curse of chanting name (Narayan) of par bharma. If someone has name Naryan with him than what else he want in life." Then onwards Narad routing all loks/srishti by chanting name Narayan Narayan but he don't have any home. [contunue...]

Comment: Thus by this story, you must have come to know that it is Dev Rishi Narad's teaching that if you have decide to spend time for Lord then there is no stopping for you. You can decide even by going against your own father.

Comment: I mistakenly used word "son" instead of "sons". His all sons decide to take sanyas, don't get confused by singular word(son).

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I have rephrased the question in order to fit the rules. I'm very sorry for going off-topic. Please tell me if there's more that I need to edit. Thank you!

Comment: @Rishabh My gratitude is with you sir! Thank you very much for sharing this valuable knowledge with me! I am still thinking about this issue and I will definitely keep this story in my mind. Thank you again very much sir!

Comment: Point of order - taking sanyasa requires mother's permission or wife's if you are married.

Comment: You should change the words like `I`, `My` from the question so that it can fit to anyone not just you. Thanks.

Comment: @PardeepKumar - I think it is more appropriate to remove any personal part. Just take this case as it is & make it as a general case without mentioning it as a personal case  ,otherwise the question still will remain as personal advice.

Comment: Triyugi Narayan Mani and SwiftPushkar, done.

Comment: If the question has "I" in it, it is still on-topic. Changing the person in the question doesn't make it eligible for reopening. It is the content which makes the question to get closed or reopened. Why are you asking for opinion? It makes the question primarily opinion based. It's the last paragraph making the question closed not the "I" and "he" in the question. Edit it out. Then the question will be reopened.

Comment: This is dup. of [Are Hindu children meant to serve their parents forever whether they like them or not?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16256/2995) even if you remove all the opinion-based stuff.

Comment: @moonstar2001"taking sanyasa requires mother's permission" - which scripture says this?

Comment: @moonstar2001 I don't think Adi Shankrachrya or Bhagwad Ramanujacharya took any consent from mother and wife respectively.

Comment: @Yogi Adi Shankaracharya took the permission of his mother but Ramanujacharya didn't take because His wife was the main reason to take up the sanyasa,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need India only to unite individual consciousness to the universal consciousness. Spiritual process is not based on geography.
2. You had gotten such father owing to your past Karmas. Following your father's wish would be your Dharma because Dharma is nothing but any act which exhausts one's Karmas. Following your father's wish will exhaust your Karmic bondings which are result of past lives & thus pave your path to unite individual consciousness to the universal consciousness.
3. Don't choose any guru until you develops razor sharp conscience to discriminate between fake & bona fide Gurus as more gurus are today fake. Till read scriptures by your own.
4. Being in a world doesn't run contrary to the Spiritual process. Leaving home is not a prerequisite to unite individual consciousness to the ultimate consciousness. Only prerequisite is to become **witness** from **enjoyer**. i.e, Drishta bhaav is only prerequisite.
5. You don't need ashram to meditate, you can meditate anytime & anywhere. If you are serious & developed **dhāran**, sitting on cozy cushion with any pose can unite you with the ultimate reality.

**Conclusion:** Follow your father's wish because it is not in conflict with spiritual process in any way.

References-

1. Obviously.
2. [Partial reference](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18397/8696).
3. Obviously.
4. Bhagvat Geeta.
5. Vijnānabhairav tantra.

[image: This pic will help to choose.]

Comment: I understand. I will try my best to balance Miri and Piri in my life and to keep my parents' will in consideration while striving to realize the Truth as well. Thank you very much sir for your guidance and knowledge! This will really help me in the future. Please do pray for me that I am successful in my life in realizing the Truth! Thank you very much again! :)

Comment: Haha @PradeepKumar you're talking as if you're never going to visit Hinduism SE again. :) . Btw, All the best.